# git does not recognize missing files

Tags: git

I have a git repo with a `.gitignore` file like this:

```
somedir/*/
```

The goal with this is to track files inside of `somedir` but don't track any folders inside `somedir` this works as I would expect when adding or modifying files. if I add a file `somedir/somefile.txt` git recognizes it as a new file, however if I add a file like `somedir/another/another.txt` this file is not tracked because it is within a sub folder of `somedir`.

The issue is with cloning this repo. When I clone the repo I do not get any of the files in `somedir` and subsequently if I do `git pull` it still does not pull in any changes. however if I do a git checkout of such files, i.e. `git checkout somedir/somefile.txt` then it brings in the file as I would expect.

Is this a known issue with git or have I run into something new?
I am using `git version 1.8.3.1`

Comment: I don't know of any such bug in Git 1.8.3.1.  That is, as Schwern noted, a very old version of Git though.  1.8.2 and 1.8.4 both fixed some common behavior items but something as fundamental as extracting a commit hasn't changed since before 1.5 (well, it has grown lots of weirdness to work around MacOS and Windows-NT things since then, but for 1.8.3.1 you must be using an old Linux).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) *only* affects which *untracked* files should remain untracked. It has no effect on what is checked out or pulled. Your problem lies elsewhere, I can't say what it is with the information given.

[`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) will tell you if you're missing any files. [`git ls-files`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) will tell you what Git considers to be checked in.

> Is this a known issue with git or have I run into something new? I am using git version 1.8.3.1

This version of Git is about seven years old, and isn't even the latest in the 1.8 series (that's 1.8.5.6). I would suggest upgrading regardless to at least 1.8.5.6 to get all the 1.8 bug fixes, and probably to the latest stable.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a known issue with git or have I run into something new?

It's not an issue with git at all; your `.gitignore` entry just doesn't say what you intend.

> The goal with this is to track files inside of somedir but don't track any folders inside somedir

So you want to ignore directories but not files. There's a way to do that, but a single `*` isn't it.

From the [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> A slash followed by two consecutive asterisks then a slash matches zero or more directories. For example, "a/**/b" matches "a/b", "a/x/b", "a/x/y/b" and so on.

So, if you want git to notice files but not directories, try:

```
somedir/**/
```

**Note:** It occurs to me that since `**` matches "zero or more directories" `somedir/**/` *might* match `somedir/`, so look out for that, and if so you may need to tweak this solution. In any case, the source of your current problem is that the `*` in `somedir/*/` matches files as well as directories.

Comment: I disagree that the pattern `somedir/*/` does not do what I think it does. for example as I said in my post, it does behave the way I would expect when adding or modifying files in the repo. Think about it this way: `somedir/*` would match all files and all directories as you have said, `somedir/*.c` would match all files ending in `.c` and so it should follow that `somedir/*/` would match all "files" that end in a `/`. which for all intents and purposes only includes directories.

Comment: `somedir/*/` should work fine here. The problem is more mysterious, since as Schwern noted, `.gitignore` can't affect actually-committed files in the first place.